# MySQL query and compare two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm very new to SQL queries, so forgive me if this is a really easy question.

I have 2 database tables `HWC` and `collection`, `HWC.id` is referenced in `collection.col`

```
HWC
- id (PRIMARY)
- stuff
- more stuff
- lots more stuff
- Year

collection
- id (PRIMARY)
- userId
- col
```

### Question:

I want to query the collection table for a specific user to see what entries from `HWC` they are missing.

I don't even know where to start logically, I don't expect anyone to build the query for me, but pointing me in the correct direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: For some reason that part didn't save, I added it back in.

Comment: Can you add some example data and expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want items from the collect that the user is *missing*.  This suggests a `left outer join`.  In particular, you want to keep everything in the `HWC` table and find those things that are missing:

```
select hwc.*
from hwc left join
     collection c
     on hwc.id = c.col
where hwc.id is null and c.user_id = @UserId;
```

When learning SQL, students often learn this syntax:

```
select hwc.*
from hwc
where hwc.id not in (select c.col from collection c where c.user_id = @UserId);
```

This is perfectly good SQL.  Some databases don't do a great job optimizing `not in`.  And, it can behave unexpectedly when `c.col` is `NULL`.  For these reasons, this is often rewritten as a `not exists` query:

```
select hwc.*
from hwc
where not exists (select 1
                  from collection c
                  where c.col = hwc.id and c.user_id = @UserId
                 );
```

I offer you these different alternatives because you are learning SQL.  It is worth learning how all three work.  In the future, you should find each of these mechanisms (`left join`, `not in`, and `not exists`) useful.

Comment: This last one works perfectly for what I needed to know! Thank you so much

Comment: Also, thanks for providing the different examples. This helps me learn which is best for my environment as well as learning SQL syntax in general.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you mean SQL JOINS.

**[SQL Joins Tutorial:](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)**

Lets say you want to Query your collection like so:

```
SELECT collection.userId, HWC.stuff
FROM collection 
INNER JOIN HWC ON collection.col = HWC.id
```

**This will pick userId from collection, and stuff from HWC, where these ID's have relations.**

Hope I helped, good luck!